# Accessing a variable by reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a reference to a variable and then update the contents in javascript, is that possible? For example a simple (fail) example would be...

```
var globalVar = 2;

function storeThis ( target, value ) {
    eval(target) = value;
}

storeThis( 'globalVar', 5);
alert('globalVar now equals ' + globalVar);
```

This of course doesn't work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eval does not return a value.

This will work:

```
window[target] = value;
```

(however, you are not passing the reference, you're passing the variable name)

Comment: digitalfresh is right, eval is for evaluation of statement so you probably need to create one e.g 
eval("window."+ target + "= " + value + ";"); but becarefull of too much recursion.

Comment: Yeah, but why `eval` at all? This is definitely not one of the few situations where `eval` is appropriate.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you both LFI and DigitalFresh, that worked a treat.

Comment: still open to better ways jasongetsdown!

Answer (score 3):

In this case the code in `storeThis` already has access to `globalVar` so there's no need to pass it in.

Your sample is identical to:

```
var globalVar = 2;

function storeThis(value) {
    globalVar = value;
}

storeThis(5);
```

What exactly are you trying to do?

Scalars can't be passed by reference in javascript. If you need to do that either use the [`Number` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or create your own object like:

```
var myObj = { foo: 2 };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use eval, you could use the following:

`var globalVar = 2;`

```
function storeThis( target, value ) {
    eval( target + ' = ' + value );
}

storeThis( 'globalVar', 5 );
alert('globalVar now equals ' + globalVar);
```

Comment: In this case, if `value` is a string, the `eval()` will treat it as a variable (if it's one word), invalid code (if it's more than one word that javascript doesn't understand) or an expression (if it's a valid javascript expression).